# Why do we still use the package keyword in Groovy / Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

in Java/Groovy, afaik, a package has to be defined in the corresponding folder. This results in all class files which are stored in `/a/b/c` start with the line `package a.b.c`. Is this still necessary? With regards to convention over configuration, this isn't DRY...

What kind of problems would arise when this package definition would be optional`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is conventional for the directory structure to match the package structure, and certain problems arise if they don't match, it is in fact not a requirement that they match.  This is also true of Java (though a lot of folks don't realize that).

Below is an example which demonstrates this.

```
groovydemo $ mkdir classes
groovydemo $ 
groovydemo $ cat src/groovy/com/demo/SomeClass.groovy 
package com.somethingotherthandemo

class SomeClass {}
groovydemo $ 
groovydemo $ groovyc -d classes/ src/groovy/com/demo/SomeClass.groovy 
groovydemo $ find classes -type f
classes/com/somethingotherthandemo/SomeClass.class
```

Comment: Notice that the src directory does not match the package structure (demo vs. somethingotherthandemo).  The compiler creates the directory structure which matches the package structure and puts the .class file there, but the source path could be just about anything.  For most situations it is a bad idea for the src path to not match the package structure, but it is valid.

Comment: Well, you wrote yourself "it is conventional" - wouldn't it make sense to go with grails one step further and make the package optional and implicit? That's what I would call "convention over ..." well not configuration but maybe habit...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "go with grails one step further".  Grails doesn't make package statements optional.  In Grails classes which don't include a package statement are in the default package just like other environments.

Comment: And that's what I think could be better - the folder could correspond to the package and thus the package declaration could be optional (which it isn't yet). But that's only my HO. I just wonder if this could be implemented through a global AST transformation :-)

Comment: With the compiler that you are imagingin, in the example I show above if you removed the package statement and didn't change anyhing else (no command line args, no other changes), would you expect the package to be src.groovy.com.demo, Users.jeff.projects.groovydemo.src.groovy.com.demo, the default (empty) package, a compile error, or something else?

Comment: Ok, I realized, that with groovy, the package name and directory the file is in are two different things. But when it comes to grails, the grails creates a default package (==app.name) when you don't specify one. So ./grails-app/domain/appname/SomeClass.groovy is expected to belong to package "appname" by grails. If I change the package name in SomeClass.groovy - all IDEs I've tested complain about the "not expected" package name. That was where my question was coming from. But I now see that changing this behaviour could cause trouble... Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for using packages in Groovy (and Grails) are some of the same reason why they are used in Java.

1. Packages serve to organize classes into logical namespaces, typically by grouping collaborating classes together.
2. It helps avoid naming conflicts with other classes (either Java or Groovy).

In any non-trival system where you have hundreds or thousands of classes, packages provide a very useful mechanism for organization and structure.

Comment: yes, what a package does is known, but what I tried to ask was if it is still needed to specify the package name if it is already known through the location in the filesystem...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is that the package name is implied by the directory the class is in, so why do you need to state it explicity? This is only true in some cases (like Grails) where there's a convention that establishes the root of the source files (e.g. `src/groovy`).

But imagine I'm writing a Groovy app and have a file at `/a/b/c/D.groovy`, how can we tell if the root of the source files is `/a` and thus the package name is `b.c` or the root of the source files is `/a/b` and therefore the package name is just `c`? As far as I can see, we can't, so the package name needs to be stated in the source file explicitly.

Comment: So, in Grails, we know the root and the package definition could be omitted. But even when we think of Groovy - the build script has to know the root of the source as starting point...

Comment: @Ralf your Groovy files don't know anything about your build configuration